# nextjs production build having different layout then development

Tags: css, next.js, darkmode

I am developing a website in which I have introduced dark theme that simply adds a class to body element.

Its working completely fine in dev env but giving issue in prod build.

here is my root layout of the app which is initialising the class that is needed to be added to body element on refresh or first visit to the site if its in dark mode.

```
import './global.css'
import './globals.scss'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Header from '@/components/global/Header'
import Footer from '@/components/global/Footer'
import Providers from '@/components/global/Providers'
import ClientToastContainer from '@/components/global/ClientToastContainer'
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react'

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
  variable: '--font-inter',
})

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Have Small Bytes',
  description: 'Byte size blogs',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const setInitialTheme = `function run() {
    let theme = window.localStorage.getItem('theme')
    if (!theme) {
      if (
        window.matchMedia &&
        window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
      ) {
        theme = ('system-dark')
      } else {
        theme = ('system-light')
      }
      window.localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
    }
      if (theme === 'dark' || theme === 'system-dark') {
      document.body.classList.add('darkTheme')
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove('darkTheme')
      }
  }
  run()`
  return (
    <Providers>
      <html lang="en" className={inter.className}>
        <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: setInitialTheme }} />
          <Header />
          {children}
          <Analytics />
          <ClientToastContainer />
          <Footer />
        </body>
      </html>
    </Providers>
  )
}
```

and here is the development build working completely fine -

[image]

and here is the production build which do not adding darkTheme class to the body element on refresh or first visit but working if I implicitly change theme after visit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So basically the issue was with me using nextjs's signin function to redirect to signin page which is making site to refresh the whole DOM which offcourse do not have the dark mode class needed to the body element to make it look dark.
I fixed the issue by removing signin function of nextjs and instead using link tag to redirect the users to signin page so that it works smoothly.